# how do I clear the v-model in the child component from the parent?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Please help me. I am trying 10hours in a row and doesn't work. I want when i clicked  in @click="cleanDataForm" in Parent Component => v-model text in Child component will "" . And i tryed do it with props , computed and nothing. I will be very kind if you help

//Parent

```
<template>
    <div class="Main">
        <div class="comment">
            <Smiles
            />
            <div class="btns">
                <button id="btn--send" type="submit" @click="sendData">Send data</button>
                <button id="btn--clear" @click="cleanDataForm">clean data</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

// Child

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <textarea
            v-model="text"                          !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1
            ref="smilesTextarea"
            placeholder="Введите комментарий"
        ></textarea>
        <button @click="showSimiles"></button>
    </div>
</template>
```

And i need this.text will "" when i clicked send data in Parent. I tryed with vuex but nothing. Please help

Comment: You can add a method in the child that clears the value. In the parent, add `refs` to the child component and in `cleanDataForm` call the child method like `this.$refs.smilresRef.clear()`.

Comment: @PrerakSola, sorry my friend, that i spend your time, but i started to learn vue and doesn't understand "add refs to the child component " it is how. Do you can undestand please?

Comment: Read all "Components In-Depth"
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing that with props and emit:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `
    <textarea
      v-model="text" 
      ref="smilesTextarea"
      placeholder="Введите комментарий"
    ></textarea>
  `,
  props: ['clear'],
  data() {
    return {
      text: ''
    }
  },
  watch: {
    clear(newVal) {
      this.text = ''
      this.$emit('cleared')
    }
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      clear: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    cleanDataForm() {
      this.clear = true
    },
    resetClear() {
      this.clear = false
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <button id="btn--clear" @click="cleanDataForm">clean data</button>
  <child :clear="clear" @cleared="resetClear"></child>
</div>
```